# Making Jsoup load only the resource needed?

Tags: java, jsoup

I'd like to load a website code for scraping purposes.

The website is filled with irrelevant pictures and various connections to different websites (like facebook). This obviously increases the loading time.

I'd really like to just read the page content, without all the other unnecessary content. Is there a way to disable external resources loading?

I can provide code, but it would be a single line with `Jsoup.connect` in it (for obvious reasons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot filter (remove) parts of the page before you load it with Jsoup.
Jsoup will load only the HTML, so it will not load the pictures or Javascript. Before loading the page you can verify that you are getting the right content - many sites contain more than one HTML file, so open your browser's developer tools, go to that site, see which files you get when you get that site and check each of them to decide if you need it or not.
This is what I get when I browse to SO:

[image: SO traffic]
As you can see - it has 14 files, but it is easy to which one is HTML and then to see if it has any interesting content.

Comment: So, when sending a GET to the page, I should be only getting the html? This seems kind of weird. Doesn't your browser also send a GET to load a page? How come the browser loads all of the other content, while jsoup loads only the html?

Comment: The browsers sends a `GET` request and gets the HTML, but then it "executes" it - the HTML contains `script` tags which tell the browser to fetch the JS (which in turn can load more HTML), `css` tags and so on. JSOUP is passive - it only loads the HTML.

Comment: Ah, I see, Thanks.